# Получения UAProf значения с устройства

Tags: android, webview

Моё приложения состоит из компонента `WebView`, который отображает мобильный сайт.
Мне нужно послать заголовок `X-wap-profile`,  который хранит в себе `URL`  на `UAProf` файл. Как мне получить  эту информацию?

Comment: Все равно ничего непонятно... Послать заголовок нужно WebView или удаленному сайту? Получить надо заголовок или UAProf файл?

Comment: нужно послать удалённому сайту.Этот  X-wap-profile заголовок хранит URL  UAProf файла ,который содержит все характеристики телефона ввиде Xml(например вот http://www.htcmms.com.tw/gen/Breeze-2.0.xml),почти в каждом устройстве храниться такая ссылка.Стандартный Браузер посылают эту ссылку ,я уже проверил.

вот нашел почти такой же вопрос на SO,но без ответа
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082934/android-how-to-get-uaprof-value-in-android-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UAProf` (`user agent profile`) генерируется стоковым браузером Android'а [Webkit](http://www.webkit.org). `WebView` по сути является компонентой `Webkit`'а, соответственно он должен брать их оттуда.

В свою очередь заголовки, которые посылает `Webkit`, берутся из свойств, задаваемых во время сборки. Свойства эти задаются в сборочном скрипте - [примеры сборочных скриптов тут](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1544487&page=395).

По сути речь идет о том, чтобы достучаться до файла `build.prop`, который обычно лежит в каталоге `/system`, который не доступен для нерутованных устройств.

Comment: Постараюсь разобраться.Спасибо

Comment: Таки по ходу дела выяснилось, что /system/build.prop вполне доступен для чтения - был неправ.